# Inner join returns same columns from two tables access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 2 tables and i'm inner join them using EID

```
CSCcode   Description   BNO        BNO-CSCcode     E_ID

05078     blah1        5430      5430-05078       1098
05026     blah2        5431      5431-05026       1077
05026     blah3        5431      5431-05026       3011
04020     blah4        8580      8580-04020       3000
07620     blah5        7560      7560-07620       7890
07620     blah6        7560      7560-07620       8560
05020     blah1        5560      5560-04020       1056
```

Second table

```
        y/n        EID

          y       1056
          n       1098
          y       1077
          n       3011
          y       3000
          n       7890 
          n       8560
```

I'm selecting all fields from table one and y/n field from table 2. but it retrieve all from table 2 including EID. I don't want to retrieve EID from table2 because result table will have two EID fields.

My query

```
SELECT *, table2 .EID
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1 .E_ID = table2 .EID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I'm selecting all fields from table one"

No, you are selecting all fields from all tables. You need to specify the table if you only want all fields from one table:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.EID
```

However, using `*` is not good practive. It's better to specify the fields that you want, so that any field that you add to the table isn't automatically included, as that might break your queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do things like this 'SELECT *, table2 .EID' - you should include all your fields from table 1. However, it is not a good practice even if you are selecting from one table.

```
SELECT 
   table1.CSCcode,
   table1.Descriptio,
   table1.BNO,
   table1.BNO-CSCcode,
   table1.E_ID, 
   table2 .EID
FROM 
   table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1 .E_ID = table2 .EID
```

Comment: Here in sample table1 it has only 5 columns, but in real it contains more than 30 columns, that's y to mention all from table1 mentioned *

Answer (score 1):

Your query is selecting everything from both tables as well as specifically the EID column from table 2. Change it to:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.y/n
...
```

Although, as stated in other answers, avoid using `*` and instead list the column names `table.columnName`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the table from which you want to select all fields modify your query to

```sql
SELECT
    table1.*, table2.EID
FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN table2
        ON table1.E_ID = table2.EID;
```

If you are using the query designer, Access sometimes sets the property `Output All Fields` of the query to `Yes`. Make sure it is set to `No` and select the fields you  want manually. (Right click in the designer and select `Properties...` in the context menu in order to see the properties.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you sometimes get stuck with a surprise `*` is because of a property in the query designer. Change this to `No` in the designer. Alternatively, like the other answers say, just remove the `*` from your query.

[image]